# How to calculate v from $\Theta \:=\:\arctan \left(\frac{v^2\pm \sqrt{v^4-g\left(gx^2+2yv^2\right)}}{gx}\right)$

Tags: trigonometry

## $\Theta \:=\:\arctan \left(\frac{v^2\pm \sqrt{v^4-g\left(gx^2+2yv^2\right)}}{gx}\right)$

What will be the formula to calculate the value of ***v*** when values of $\Theta$, $g$, $x$ and $y$ is already known.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_of_a_projectile
Go to section Angle $\Theta$ required to hit coordinate (x,y).

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: @nayrb. It is just quadratic.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, yup! Got confused in my head expanding--I was looking for cancelation.

Answer (score 1):

since it resembles the form of root of a quadratic equation.a quadratic equation in $\tan\theta$ can be constructed.
$$\frac{gx}{2}\tan^2\theta-v^2\tan\theta+\frac{(gx^2+2yv^2)}{2x}=0$$
further find expression for $v$.